# How to solve this recurrence?

Tags: recurrence-relations

$ E_{n}=2E_{n-1}+ 2^{n-1} $

Can anyone help me to solve this recurrence? Is there a general way to think about recurrence?

Comment: Is there any initial condition? i.e. $E_0$ or $E_1$?

Answer (score 1):

\begin{align*}
E_1&=2 E_0 + 2^0\\
E_2&=2 E_1 + 2^1=4 E_0+ 2^1+2^1\\
E_3&=2 E_2 + 2^2=8 E_0+ 2^2+2^2+2^2
\end{align*}

Answer (score 0):

A general solution is of the form:
$$E_n=c2^n + n2^{n-1},$$
where $c$ is any real constant.

I found one solution, the $n2^{n-1}$ part, by an educated guess, which I realize probably isn't that helpful for you. Then given one solution, I solved the recurrence,
$$B_n=2B_{n-1}$$
to get get the $c2^n$ part. Observe that adding the two together still gives a solution to your recurrence.

Comment: You are talking about guess. Can you prove it?

Comment: Sure, it's easy to prove it's a solution - just plug the expression into both sides of your recurrence. The guesswork was trying a solution of that form. I don't really have an explanation for that choice, it was just based on experience of solving these sorts of problems before.